# What is this symbol `¬` and how to remove it from an MS Word 2013 file?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, unicode, ocr, symbols

I used a OCR program to convert some scanned pages to an ms word file.

After the conversion is possible to found the symbol `¬` in the middle of many words.

I tried to *search and replace* it but word is not able to detect it.

What is it and how can I remove it?

Comment: The symbol is logical negation

Comment: One thing you may want to do is to investigate why OCR has inserted it in the first place.

Comment: which hec editor should i use, or is there a online one.

Comment: @AndrewLeach dont know, it showed options like ectract only text and other things like that, besides now i have edited this document I cant do the work again, so how to correct this document.

Comment: It is an invisible that indicates a carriage return (I think). You can disable it in settings.

Answer (score 3):

**¬** is an optional hyphen in Word, you can add it manually by pressing **CTRL** + **-**. Your OCR software seems to be so smart that it automatically adds this.

Check the documentations on hyphens at https://support.office.com/article/Hyphenate-text-manually-f2007328-ee57-4c60-9d2a-91c7d8845cf6.

Comment: the ocr is good "omini dragon" but it has added the special hyphen in too many places where it is not needed. I need to submit the document but dont have time to manually remove the symbol so please help.

Comment: for printouts this will not be visible, correct?

Comment: nope it is visible. (:

Comment: Then this is not the optional hyphen of word, but a character that is inserted by OCR.

When copying to clipboard and pasting it in the seach dialog in cannot be found, correct? 

What if you copy your text to notepad and try to replace it there?

Comment: _What if you copy in notepad ?_... you will lose all the format of word that maybe the _ocr_ have done, but it should work. Maybe better _notepad++_ and to pass though a _"human readable"_ format (`rtf`,`html`,`xml`...)

Comment: yes i can select it in notepad but after doing so the file becomes unreadable in ms word, it askes for a repair option. so how do i remove that symbol from ms office file

Comment: I meant to copy the paragraph that contains the characters to clipboard, then open notepad, paste it there. Then you remove the characters in Notepad and copy it to clipboard again, paste it in Word. Does this work?

Answer (score 1):

In Word 2010/13 you can replace (find and replace - CTRL+H) the "Logical negation" symbol by using the "optional hyphen"instead.

Answer (score 0):

From [Unicodelookup](https://unicodelookup.com/#%C2%AC/1) you get

```
Unicode character   Oct     Dec     Hex     HTML
¬   not sign        0254    172     0xAC    &not;
```

From  [www.fileformat.info](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ac/index.htm) you can readmore

```
¬ Negation  U+00AC
```

Then you can follow the official help to [substitute special characters](https://support.office.com/article/Find-and-replace-text-and-other-data-in-a-Word-document-c6728c16-469e-43cd-afe4-7708c6c779b7), or better [here](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/214204).

Try with `^u00AC` as special char to search for.
In some version of word, if you select the symbol (special character) and you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> you will get the desired Unicode value decrypted for you.

**Reference**

- [Write with *unicode* in ms word](https://sites.google.com/site/projectcodebank/Do-It-Yourself/write-with-unicode-in-ms-word)

Comment: example text:  "Pralidoxime should not be adminis¬tered without concurrent atropine administration. In ani¬mal experiments"      I tried to search the special character with the hex value it did not work.

Comment: Try to substitute that symbol with nothing :-). If you want try before to search for it. You can try to paste in the search textbox, the symbol `¬`, if as it seems, will not work, try with `^u00AC`. If not select one symbol `¬` and press `Alt+x` and read the code you have.

Comment: Did you try to select the symbol and press `Alt+x` to read its Unicode? If it works, you can try to search for it with `^u00AC` or what it will answer you word. In same old versions it worked even to paste the special symbol.

Comment: in the word i tried the alt+x but it does not show anything, do i have to enable the option somewhere. also I tried pasting the symbol but its not working also the code "u00AC" did not return any results.

Comment: I take your comment literally. You should add `^` before: it should be `^u00AC` and not `u00AC`. Try it with `u` and `U`... (I've not word with me).

Comment: yes i add the "^" and also tried the caps and small combination its not detecting it.

Comment: It has to be a way to do it inside Word. As workaround you can save the file as `rtf` (or in `html` but you can lose more formats, or `xml`...) then you can look inside it with notepad (better notepad++) find the "symbol block" and _kill all them_, save it and come back to word. Not elegant but it should work. Can you update a link with a little piece of the file?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and i just selected ^- (optional hyphen) on that place where the symbol ¬ shows and then I fire the replace and it works!

**Example**

Like your word is showing when you paste it on the find: **This¬ is** 
Then change back it to on the find field: **This^- is**

And the type the replace word and it will work!

Answer (score 0):

In MS Word open Office Button > Word options > Display 
In "Alway show these formatting marks on the screen" make on ☑ "Optional hyphens" checkbox.
Now you can simply change the ¬ symbol to nothing in Replace (Ctrl+H).